# Bootstrap Typeahead with Parse.com

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, parse-platform, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to use `typeahead` with Parse.com results. I thought that `Parse` returns `JSON` objects, but it seems that following method doesn't recognize it. Can anyone spot what's wrong? Or maybe there is easier way to make it work (at the end  I want to be able to search through two field of each object).

As far I get to this (thanks to this: https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead):

```
function queryListy(){
    Parse.Cloud.run('queryList', {}, {
        success: function(result) {      
          var $input = $('#query');       
          $input.typeahead({source:result, 
            autoSelect: true}); 
          $input.change(function() {
                var current = $input.typeahead("getActive");
                if (current) {
                    // Some item from your model is active!
                    if (current.name == $input.val()) {
                        // This means the exact match is found. Use toLowerCase() if you want case insensitive match.
                    } else {
                        // This means it is only a partial match, you can either add a new item 
                        // or take the active if you don't want new items
                    }
                } else {
                    // Nothing is active so it is a new value (or maybe empty value)
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(error) {
           console.log(error);
          }
    });
}
```

When I put `[{id: "someId1", name: "Display name 1"}, {id: "someId2", name: "Display name 2"}]` instead of `result` it works so basic mechanism seems to be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse does not return objects in a form that you can use directly. You need to call `get` on every property you need:

```
var mappedObjects = [];
result.forEach(function(parseObject){
  mappedObjects.push({
    id: parseObject.id, //id is special, you don't need get
    name: parseObject.get("name"), //generic fields need get
  });
});
$input.typeahead({source:mappedObjects, ...
```

If you'd prefer, you can do this mapping in your cloud code instead so that your client-side code doesn't need to.